# ¿Cómo enviar datos a todos los clientes usando 'express-ws'?

Tags: nodejs, websocket

Estoy empezando con los `websockets` usando `express-ws`.

Tengo la siguiente situación:

Puedo recibir mensajes de los clientes, pero mi servidor sólo responde a quien envió la información. O sea `usuario1` envió: `"Hola mundo"`
entonces `usuario1` recibió respuesta: `"Hola mundo"`, pero el resto de usuarios no reciben nada. La intención es que todos lo reciban.

Aquí les dejo el código:

```js
app.ws('/mensajes', (ws, req)=>{
  ws.on('message',msg => ws.send(msg));
});
```

Pero eso sólo responde el mensaje al mismo que lo mandó.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea enviar un mensaje a todos los clientes conectados al Servidor [`websockets/ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws) creado mediante el paquete [`express-ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws).

Se utiliza el método [`send()`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#websocketsenddata-options-callback) del objeto `ws`, el cual es una instancia de la Clase [`WebSocket`](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#class-websocket).

Dicho método sólo envía un mensaje al cliente que originó el evento `message`. Se desea enviar un mensaje a todos los clientes conectados al servidor.

**SOLUCIÓN**

El tipo de mensaje que deseas enviar es conocido como **difusión** (*broadcast*) y es el tipo de mensaje que se envía a todos los clientes conectados al servidor.

El método `send()` por si solo no funciona para enviar este tipo de mensaje, y no existe un método directo para enviar un mensaje de este tipo en `websockects`. Por lo cual debemos crear nuestro propio método.

Para ello necesitamos conocer la lista de clientes conectados al Servidor. Esto lo logramos usando el método [`getWss()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws#wsinstancegetwss) que tiene una propiedad llamada `clients` la cual es una lista de **todos** los clientes conectados al servidor WS.

La forma de obtener esta lista es:

```js
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

// ...

const clients = expressWS.getWss().clients;
```

Ahora, para enviar el mensaje de difusión a todos los clientes conectados, podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```js
clients.forEach(client => {
  client.send('Hola mundo');
});
```

Nuestro código (muy sencillo) podría quedar así:

```js
const expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);

//...

app.ws('/mensajes', (ws, req)=>{
  ws.on('message', msg => {
    const clients = expressWS.getWss().clients;
    clients.forEach(client => {
      client.send(msg);
    });
  });
});
```

De esta forma cada usuario conectado al servidor WS recibirá el mensaje.

Esto es una solución al problema planteado en la pregunta. Sin embargo, hay un par de detalles con la lógica de este código:

1. El mensaje enviado por un cliente será devuelto a todos los usuarios incluyendo al mismo cliente.
2. El mensaje será enviado a **todos** los clientes, no sólo a aquellos que hayan accedido a una ruta específica.

Esos problemas serían parte de otra pregunta y si ese es el caso, te invito a realizar la misma en el sitio.

Comment: Gracias y si tengo algunas otras preguntas 
A) como mando a un grupo especifico de usuarios? en http se puede haciendo X validacion para luego guardar y enviar a quien solicite los datos pero en websockets como valido y envio solo a ciertas personas? 
Hay alguna pagina, documentacion etc donde pueda tener toda esta informacion?